# Nontrivial matrix $A^3=A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to exist nontrivial matrices such that $A^2=A^3$ and $A=A^T$ but that $\text{Tr}(A)=x$ and $\text{Tr}(A^2)=y$ such that $0<x,y<1$? I was actually wanting a matrix that has this sort of sequence relation $A,A^2,A^2,A^2,\dots$ when we have some sequence of compositions; however idempotent matrices always have trace equal to the rank and therefore cannot have traces between zero or one. Also multiples of identity do not work. Clearly we would need to have that $\det(A)=1$ but this implies that the matrices are in $SO(N)$ and rotations will not have this sequence structure $A,A^2,A^2,\dots$ as far as I can see. Is it possible? Maybe going to complex matrices helps in giving more degrees of freedom.

An argument for the existence/non-existence would suffice. If it is too trivial just hints are enough as well.

Comment: If $A^2 = A^3$, then we must have $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A^2)$. Also, $\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ will be an integer.

Comment: By nontrivial, you mean $A^2 = A^3$ but $A\ne A^2$, correct? I believe this is impossible under the constraint $A = A^T$. Without that constraint, matrices that have Jordan blocks with eigenvalue 0 and size 2 will have this property.

Comment: @eyeballfrog that is a very interesting comment, thank you very much. I will look into it.

Comment: I suppose this is 'trivial', but A=(0,0 ; 0,1) does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple argument for non-existence: note that if $A^2 = A^3$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 = \lambda^3$, which means that $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$. It follows that $\operatorname{tr}(A^k) = \operatorname{tr}(A)$ for all positive integers $k$.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem elegantly.

Comment: All $k$ except $k=0$ (just nitpicking).

Comment: @Marc Fair point; edited